# Can 2 different ODE's have the same set of solutions?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

If I have two differents linear ODE's:
\begin{equation} x'' + p(t)x' + q(t)x = f(t) . \quad p,q \in C(I,\infty). \\ x'' + j(t)x' + g(t)x = h(t). \quad j,g \in C(I,\infty).
\end{equation}

Coul they have exactly the same set of solutions?

And if we have two different non-linear ODE's could they?

Comment: I think the first obvious question is what do you mean by different? I could take the first ODE, multiply it by 2, and get a ``new" ODE.

Comment: I mean that $p(t) \neq j(t)$ or $q(t) \neq g(t) $ or $f(t) \neq h(t). For some $ t \in I$

Comment: Not likely. A system of 1st order equations (and higher orders can usually reduced to first order by replacing derivatives with new variables) will define a vector field to which every solution is tangent. If the two systems define different fields the solutions will diverge even if they were identical at the start.

Answer (score 2):

If your ODE's are $x^{(n)}=F(t,x,x',\dots,x^{(n-1)})$ and $G(t,x,x',\dots,x^{(n-1)})$, for some $F,G:\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ and they both have the same local solutions for any initial conditions, then we must have $F=G$: if not, just take a value $v=(t_0,x_0,x_0',\dots,x_0^{(n-1)})$ such that $F(v)\neq G(v)$ and then your local solution at $v$ will be different in both equations, as both solutions will have different $n^\text{th}$ derivatives.

In the linear case, for the equations you give we would have the functions $F(t,x,x')=-p(t)x' - q(t)x - f(t)$ and $G(t,x,x')=-j(t)x' - g(t)x - h(t)$. So if they have the same solutions, we need $F(t,x,x')=G(t,x,x')\;\forall t,x,x'$, which implies $p(t)=j(t),q(t)=g(t),f(t)=h(t)$: if for example $p(t_0)\neq j(t_0)$ for some $t_0$, then $F(t_0,0,s)=-sp(t_0)-f(t_0)$ and $G(t_0,0,s)=-sj(t_0)-h(t_0)$, so $F(t_0,0,s)$ cannot be equal to $G(t_0,0,s)\;\forall s$, contradicting $F=G$. Similar arguments can be used to show $q(t)=g(t)$ and $f(t)=h(t)$.